# Setting up priority of packets that are being transmitted over the network

Tags: network-programming

I am working on a project wherein I am implementing a MAC protocol. My first task is to implement priority based scheduling of packets. To be more specific, I want to schedule the transmission of packets such that certain types of packets which are more important than the others will be allotted higher priority than the rest of the packets.

I have been trying to establish this since quite sometime now and have used various approaches to achieve the same.

There are certain bits in the IP header which are allotted for setting the priority of the packets that are being transmitted. I have used socket programming to be able to achieve the same. I also tried it using raw sockets but it was causing some problems and was not working the way I wanted it to.

So I turned back to normal SOCK_DGRAM and SOCK_STREAM. But I am still facing some problems.

Can anyone help me regarding this?

Comment: What do you mean by "*MAC protocol*"? I took that to mean a layer-2 or layer-3 protocol, but then you talk about IP.

Comment: the MAC protocol will consist of prioritising traffic that is leaving a certain node in a network. But to accomplish this, I am trying to build the IP header which will be appended to the packets that are being transmitted. I am not bound to only the MAC layer. The final aim is to prioritize traffic and hence I called it a MAC protocol. Might have been confusing. Sorry for that. Can you help me with this?